# NSURLRequest HTTPS problems - iphone

Tags: iphone, https, sdk

I am creating an NSURLMutableRequest and setting HTTP methods and content-types and such. All was working fine until my last compile. I now get this in the Console, but the app doesn't crash:
CODE:

```
Internal error.
Exception from other package:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

and then the program continues. Code can be posted if you need it. The URL I am contacting is:

https://apps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway

This is VERISIGN not some Joe Blow make-your-own SSL cert.

Thanks guys!

Comment: your getting this Java error in the console of your Cocoa Touch app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have researched. QBOE XML processor is down.